# Changing "on-premises mastered Directory Sync objects"

Tags: azure-active-directory

Sometimes you ask yourself a question and cannot answer or google the answer.

**Question:**
Is there any way to turn a single "on-premises mastered Directory Sync objects", to a "cloud mastered object"? Specificly a user account.

Can I revert this if I try with a real account?

And the major question: Thoughts about the consequences?

**Background:**
We move more and more processes to the cloud and I am beginning to "feel the need" for changing this. So I want to investigate the consequenses of changing, what breaks and what makes the change (if possible).

**We have:**
Office365 (mail,sharepoint, etc), onprem ADFS, AzureAD Sync. I am most worried about ADFS, since the account must be able to authenticate onprem. ~20.000 users and a applications onprem of all sorts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you aware in synced identities objects are mastered in our on-premise AD structure and cannot change it. If we need to make changes and edits to any of our users, this needs to be made on our on-premises AD structure. Once those changes are made, Azure AD Connect will then synchronize those up to Azure AD, and you'll see those changes after the next synchronization run.

Mostly  Azure AD Connect assumes you start with a new Azure AD tenant and that there are no users or other objects there. But if you have started with an Azure AD tenant, populated it with users and other objects, and now want to use Connect, then kindly check this [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-install-existing-tenant.md).